# Fixing 'Invalid Filename' Deploy Error in Hugo

Tags: hugo, netlify

I've deployed my Hugo website using Netlify, but after my latest changes I keep getting the same error that is as follows:

> Failed during stage 'deploying site': Invalid filename 'tags/c#/page/1/index.html'. Deployed filenames cannot contain # or ? characters

I can't find any file in my repository that contains such a path and my index.html doesn't contain any of those invalid characters either. I have attempted to revert the changes but I still receive the same deployment error.

Where should I be looking in my repo files to diagnose this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is pointing to an auto-generated file that lists those pages that have 'C#' as a tag in the front matter. So look for pages that have something like:

```
tags: [ 'C#']
```

in it.

In order fix, you will need to change the tag to 'c-sharp' or something similar.

Or - check that `preserveTaxonomyNames` is not in your site.yml (or is set to false).

Comment: I found the bug! I had a markdown file containing the tag C# which clearly doesn't support the # character. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This error happens when we use C# tag or other that contains `#` in our post/markdown because Hugo will generate static files in public folder according to the tag such as `tags/c#/index.xml`.

We certainly can replace with other tag like C-Sharp or similar but if we still want to see C# tag in our post there is a workaround for that.

After replacing the tag with `C-Sharp` for example.

```yaml
tags: ["C-Sharp"]
```

We need to override html file where this new tag will appear, then replace following code

```html
<a href="{{ "/tags/" | relLangURL }}{{ . | urlize }}/">{{ . }}</a>
```

with

```html
<a href="{{ "/tags/" | relLangURL }}{{ . | urlize }}/">{{ replace . "-Sharp" "#" }}</a>
```

Please notice we replace `-Sharp` with `#` so that `C#` will still appear on our post but the url will be `[your-site]/tags/c-sharp/` and Hugo won't generate `tags/c#/index.xml` in public folder. Therefore, we can avoid the error.

This is summarized from [here](https://www.byteinthesky.com/tutorials/how-to-fix-invalid-filename-deploy-error-in-hugo/).